# Perl Archive::Zip Issue. Zip files become un-openable when using addString with 'large' files

Tags: perl, zip

So I have a Perl system that is taking emails and splitting them into JSON files and attachments, then zipping them up.
My process works really well, however I have noticed that the output zip file (created using Archive::Zip) is actually invalid when an input attachment is over roughly 10MB.

my code is:

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$count = 0;
foreach $attachment (@atachments) {
   my $member = $zip->addString(@attachments[$count], @attachment_names[$count])
   $member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_STORED );
   $count++;
}
my $jsonMember = $zip->addString($json, $fn . '.json')
$jsonMember->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_STORED );

unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed($out) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'zip error';
}
```

So this works completely fine for things less than 10MB, however randomly whenever an attachment is more than 10MB, it stops working as expected.... the output zip file is seen in Windows as being less than I think it should be and the zip file cannot be opened/extracted.

I have tried upgrading Archive::Zip to version 1.68 and no luck.
I have tried different compression levels and also no luck.

the string itself is fine and I can verify its all there...
but I was wondering if someone knew if addString had a potential string limit somewhere.

Could it potentially be varying the zip type based on the filesize, I see some stuff online about zip64, but that mentions only after 4GB...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not compile - there are missing semicolons are the end of some of the lines.

Here is a modified version that runs stand-alone.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );

my $out = "test.zip";
my @attachments = ('alpha'  x (1024 * 1024 * 10), # create a large file
                   'beta'   x (1024 * 1024 * 10), # create a large file,
                   'gaamma' x (1024 * 1024 * 10), # create a large file
                  );

my @attachment_names = ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

for my $count (0 .. @attachments -1) {
   my $member = $zip->addString($attachments[$count], $attachment_names[$count]) ;
   $member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_STORED );
}

my $json = 'json';
my $fn = 'something';
my $jsonMember = $zip->addString($json, $fn . '.json') ;
$jsonMember->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_STORED );

unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed($out) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'zip error';
}
```

Running that produced a file called `test.zip`.

```
$ unzip -l test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
 52428800  2023-10-10 15:54   name1
 41943040  2023-10-10 15:54   name2
 62914560  2023-10-10 15:54   name3
        4  2023-10-10 15:54   something.json
---------                     -------
157286404                     4 files
```

The zip file is valid

```
$ unzip -t test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
    testing: name1                    OK
    testing: name2                    OK
    testing: name3                    OK
    testing: something.json           OK
No errors detected in compressed data of test.zip.
```

A 10 meg file is perfectly normal file for `Archive::Zip`.  You only need zip64 if

- an individual file is > 4Gig
- the individual entries are less than 4 gig, but the combinded size of the zip file is > 4 gig
- there are more than 64k entries in the zip file

If none of those apply, the problem is elsewhere & you need to supply a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply pmqs. Apologies my code wasn't great, I was copying it from my server's command line onto my laptop by eye :D

Comment: So I didn't realise the unzip package had a test functionality, and having used that using one of my tests it returns:
End of central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zip file, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.

So is there any reason you know of why it wouldnt do the die 'zip error', if it failing to write the full zip file?

Comment: The "End of central-directory signature not found` message can be trigger by a number of things. Firstly - the file isn't a zip file at all. Secondly, and I suspect this the the issue for you - the end of the zipfile hasn't been written for some reason. Perhaps the program was interrupted whist writing. If your code always follow the pattern in you code, I don't see how it could fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to pmqs for the time to answer my question, unfortunately it was actually me being a bit stupid.

So I have Apache NiFi pulling from the `$out` directory and was set to allow files with minimum file ages of 0s. (With the idea being I didn't think I needed to add unnatural delay).

I am guessing that Zip::Archive potentially writes to the directory in chunks, when handling larger files, and this was triggering my NiFi server to pre-emptively pull the file for processing, and delete the zip.

I have set a minimum file age of 2s and it has fixed this issue.

Comment: Good to hear it working. My recollection is that  Archive::Zip works does all the writing to disk when you call `writeToFileNamed`.

Comment: In my testing, in the hundreds of small-medium files (anywhere 1kb to 1MB), there has not been a single issue. Even 6MB tests worked without failure.
I don't have the NiFi system setup with any specific polling rate, it is set to look for new files and then pull them immediately when they pop u.

My thought process was that until it was finished writing, the file would be locked from any read access. But it appears that that maybe is not the case somehow.

Whats also odd is that Zip::Archive wasn't throwing any errors when its ZIP file was stolen from it :D

Comment: added a better fix than artificial 2s delay. I have Archive::Zip writing to one directory, then using File::Copy move() command to move it to a second directory, where NiFi picks it up.

Seems to solve my problem in a fast, but potentially more system intensive, solution